# GPU/CPU for 3D Blu-ray playback

Tags: hardware-rec, blu-ray, 3d-multimedia, arcsoft

I'm struggling to find good information on what hardware I need to get stutter free 3D Blu-ray playback on my PC.

Do I need to get a graphics card that supports 3D Blu-ray hardware acceleration? If so, what's the cheapest one that has it? I've heard people say that you have to get an AMD 6XXX series graphics card, is that really necessary? They don't even exist in low profile (which I need).

Or do you just need a beefy CPU? If so, what's the minimum for getting good quality playback?

I currently have a Phenom II X2 CPU and am using the motherboards onboard HD4200 graphics. It uses 100% CPU and stutters *very* slightly.

I'm using Arcsoft TMT5 for playback.

I also tried using a dedicated HD5450 GPU with hardware acceleration enabled/disabled in TMT, and it still had the slight stuttering. I assume it's not actually doing any hardware acceleration as the CPU usage seems to be the same (~100%).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using CoreAVC. :)

Comment: I need Arcsoft TMT for WMC integration unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, I've found that a Phenom II X4 CPU + on board graphics is all that's needed to get stutter free 3D BluRay playback.

If anyone can vouch for any other budget setups that play 3D BluRay smoothly, feel free to add an answer!

Comment: Which CPU? 955?